# How to access String from one class to another?

Tags: java, string, inheritance

So for example I have 2 classes and one interface.

```
public class mainClass {

    private String word;

}



public interface intWord {

     public String getOutput();

     public void setInput( String input );

     public void setLevel ( int level );

}



public class secondClass implements intWord {

//class I want to be able to access 'word' from mainClass without extending it.

     public String getOutput()    {

     }

     public void setInput( String input )    {

     }

     public void setLevel ( int level )    {

     }

}
```

How do I go about accessing "word" in my secondClass without extending mainClass to it? I believe I can add some helper methods somewhere to make it easy....but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 2):

In your mainClass you can add a "getter" method, as seen below

```
 public class mainClass {

    private String word;

    public String getWord(){
         return word;
    }

 }
```

And just call getWord() from your second class

You can also dynamically set your word value from your second class by adding a setter method:

```
 public void setWord(String newWord){
      word = newWord;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a getWord() and a setWord(String word)

Function Within mainClass and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do assuming you want to use "word" as parameter for your setInput method will be to have an instance of mainClass and a getter to access the field word. Here is what it will look like:

```
public static void main( String args[])
{
    // Assuming word is not null
    secondClass second_class = new secondClass ();
    secondclass.setInput(mainClass.getWord());
}
```

The other way will be to have your field word be sa static variable and return it with a static getter(Not recommended). Here is what you mainClass should look like:

```
public class mainClass {

     private static String word;

     public static String getWord(){
        return word;
     }
}
```

And here is how you will access it:

```
public static void main( String args[])
{
    mainClass mainclass = new mainClass();
    // Assuming word is not null
    secondClass second = new secondClass ();
    secondclass.setInput(mainClass.getWord());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create setters and getters for `private String word;` in `mainClass` and create an object of mainClass in `secondClass` and access the getters and setters to get/set the value of `word`.
Another thing, if you know that `word` is global variable then you can create it as `public string word;` instead of private and `extend` mainClass in secondClass so as to access it directly.

Just for your knowledge java follows convention where class name should start with capital letter and then follow camel case.